# Wired connection not working (on Ubuntu 14.10)

Tags: ethernet, 14.10, wired

## The problem

As from the title, I am not able to establish a wired connection with my *HP Pavilion dv7-2215el* on *Ubuntu* 14.10 anymore. I've read possibly every related question, but none of those have helped me fixing my problem, so I am now thinking that the *Ethernet* chip has fried :(

### Some details

Here I am posting some details about my current situation. I hope someone can spot something and/or suggest me some other tests and/or provide a solution.

```
ifconfig
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:26:9e:74:21:4d
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
          Interrupt:46 Base address:0x6000

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:990 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:990 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
          RX bytes:82952 (82.9 KB)  TX bytes:82952 (82.9 KB)

wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 0c:ee:e6:9a:8c:4d
          inet addr:10.0.0.11  Bcast:10.0.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::eee:e6ff:fe9a:8c4d/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:5241 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:54415
          TX packets:5272 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:1958537 (1.9 MB)  TX bytes:1087330 (1.0 MB)
          Interrupt:16
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
cat /etc/network/interfaces
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
cat /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf
[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile,ofono
dns=dnsmasq

no-auto-default=00:26:9E:74:21:4D,

[ifupdown]
managed=false
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
dmesg | grep -e eth0 -e Eth
[    0.929043] r8168 Gigabit Ethernet driver 8.039.00-NAPI loaded
[   19.451371] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth0: link is not ready
[   23.656823] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[   24.431047] eth0: 0xffffc90000656000, 00:26:9e:74:21:4d, IRQ 46
[   24.458314] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth0: link is not ready
[   24.458584] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth0: link is not ready
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
nm-tool

NetworkManager Tool

State: connected (global)

- Device: eth0 -----------------------------------------------------------------
  Type:              Wired
  Driver:            r8168
  State:             unavailable
  Default:           no
  HW Address:        00:26:9E:74:21:4D

  Capabilities:
    Carrier Detect:  yes

  Wired Properties
    Carrier:         off


- Device: wlan0  [HOME-9885] ---------------------------------------------------
  Type:              802.11 WiFi
  Driver:            wl
  State:             connected
  Default:           yes
  HW Address:        0C:EE:E6:9A:8C:4D

  Capabilities:
    Speed:           54 Mb/s

  Wireless Properties
    WEP Encryption:  yes
    WPA Encryption:  yes
    WPA2 Encryption: yes

  Wireless Access Points (* = current AP)
    *HOME-9885:      Infra, 58:23:8C:2D:98:85, Freq 2412 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 76 WPA WPA2
    bear09:          Infra, C8:D7:19:D1:47:89, Freq 2437 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 79 WPA WPA2
    NETGEAR14:       Infra, 44:94:FC:94:E8:7E, Freq 2462 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 70 WPA2
    medialink201:    Infra, 14:35:8B:0C:96:88, Freq 2442 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 60 WPA
    APT 12102:       Infra, 98:FC:11:D5:60:29, Freq 2412 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 37 WPA2
    NETGEAR85:       Infra, 44:94:FC:3E:2F:95, Freq 2462 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 32 WPA2
    HP-Print-27-ENVY 4500 series: Infra, 28:80:23:ED:62:27, Freq 2427 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 20 WPA2
    xfinitywifi:     Infra, 5A:23:8C:2D:98:87, Freq 2412 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 97
    Dlink_1:         Infra, 1C:BD:B9:B1:40:E0, Freq 2417 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 17 WPA2
    AsusE:           Infra, 10:BF:48:3D:16:5B, Freq 2422 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 15 WPA2
    The League 2:    Infra, 08:86:3B:19:81:48, Freq 2437 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 35 WEP
    belkin.648:      Infra, 08:86:3B:19:06:48, Freq 2442 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 72 WPA WPA2
    belkin.18a:      Infra, 08:86:3B:19:81:8A, Freq 2462 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 27 WPA WPA2
    belkin.f4c:      Infra, 08:86:3B:17:3F:4C, Freq 2432 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 17 WPA WPA2

  IPv4 Settings:
    Address:         10.0.0.11
    Prefix:          24 (255.255.255.0)
    Gateway:         10.0.0.1

    DNS:             75.75.75.75
    DNS:             75.75.76.76
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
sudo lshw -c network

  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       logical name: eth0
       version: 02
       serial: 00:26:9e:74:21:4d
       size: 10Mbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list rom ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=half latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=MII speed=10Mbit/s
       resources: irq:46 ioport:5000(size=256) memory:d1010000-d1010fff memory:d1000000-d100ffff memory:d1020000-d102ffff
```

In the case this is a HW failure, what do you suggest for replacing the Ethernet chip functionality? Some kind of *USB* to *Ethernet* converter? Else?

---

### Some tests

The following tests didn't help fixing the problem

```
sudo modprobe r8168
```

Nor assigning a manual *IP*

```
dhclient eth0
ifconfig eth0 10.0.0.100/24 up
route add default gw 10.0.0.1
```

Comment: Whats the output of **lshw -c network**? The **State: unavailable** can be due to faulty cable, physical problem on card, port problem on the other end etc. If its possible try to replace the cable at first and then check again, check the **syslog** then.

Comment: I've updated the question with the output of `lshw -c network`. I've tried several cables and several connections (home and at work). And [this](https://gist.github.com/7d2c08162dc5ebf1e9ac.git) is my `dmesg` output. Oh, and both LEDs are always weakly ON.